# Entity Framework : Filter nested collection by value of its properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have model as below

```
class MyClass()
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

both are added to `DBContext` as `DbSets`, now I would like to filter out the `MyClass` using the value of the `Name` property in the `Items` collection. How do I do this?

Comment: They are two different questions, they just have the same model.

Comment: They're essentially the same. Besides that, it would help to show what you tried, because it's not clear at which level you need help. If you show where you're stuck you may get more specific help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all correct your POCOs this way:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual MyClass MyClass {get;set}
   public int MyClassId {get;set}
}
```

**Usage:**

Presented query will return all `MyClass` instances, where **at least one** item's `Name` will satisfy condition:

```
var answer = db.MyClass.Where(c => c.Items.Any(item => item.Name == "Sam")).ToList();
```

This query will return all `MyClass` instances, where **all** item's `Name` will satisfy condition:

```
var answer = db.MyClass.Where(c => c.Items.All(item => item.Name == "Sam")).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need to use joins for your queries. `db.MyClass.Where(c => c.Items.Any(item => item.Name == "Sam"))` is equivalent to your first query and (IMO) simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.